# How do I properly set up a spotlight cone?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light

I'm having a problem while rendering a searchlight-style spot lamp (i.e. I want to see the "light cone" in the final render ("Halo" option is checked), a.k.a. volumetric light).

It appears that the cone is not actually interrupted by other objects. Simplified example for illustration purposes:

- point a spot lamp with a relatively narrow cone (e.g. 10° ) and "Halo" option enabled at the middle of a plane so that the spot is entirely on the plane.
- render the whole setup from the side so you can see both sides of the plane
- -> the spot's light cone will continue beyond the plane:

[image]

Is that a bug? If not, what would I have to do to stop the light cone from "penetrating" the plane? Note that the actual spot is only visible on the upper plane, not the bottom one. Also, if I place another object within the cone it will properly cast a shadow onto the next surface. It does not affect the "shape" of the light cone however, as I would expect...

I'm currently using Blender 2.69.8 Fastest Build from graphicall.org but also had this problem with the original 2.69 release.

*(remainder of original text moved to new question: ["Why do my spotlight's dimensions differ between rendered and non-rendered view?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6314/1259)*

Comment: Asking more than one question in a single post is discouraged. Please split this into two separate questions. (Regarding your second question, try resetting the scale on your lamp with `Alt`+`S`)

Comment: @gandalf3 : Done. See link in edited text for new question. Feel free to add your answer there again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for the spot lamp to be blocked by other objects, you must set the *Step* to at least 1:

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is already looking a whole lot better. Thanks! :)  Any ideas on the second issue? (probably should have posted that as a separate question, I guess)

Comment: @OliverGiesen It's not too late, you can click the edit button below your question and copy-paste the second part into a new question. As for ideas, see my [first comment above](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/how-do-i-properly-set-up-a-spotlight-cone/6299?noredirect=1#comment10010_6298).

Comment: Yes, I was already planning on doing that tonight when I'm back home. BTW: From a cursory check (it was already 4am at the time), your tip rgd. Spotlight scaling appears to have been spot on! ;)