# Creating Batman Symbol Spotlight

Tags: rendering, materials, light

How can I use the spotlight in blender to cast shadows such and the batman symbol, or other "cool" lighting effects. I went into the compositor and tried assigning it a material, but that didn't work.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/sunbeams-in-blender on step 3.5 you'd use whatever superhero's logo you want...

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to state that I am trying to accomplish this within cycles.

Comment: Please don't ask tutorial-like questions. They're too broad and don't really fit the scope of the site. Instead ask specific questions: i.e. "How to create a spotlight effect in Cycles" or "How to project a shape with a lamp in Cycles".