# Is it possible to make visible spotlight lightrays?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

I'm using a Spotlight on one of my scenes, first I planned to make the effect of the lightrays on other editing software, but maybe it's possible on Blender. It is possible to make a spotlight look like the image below? (also, I'm using cycles)

Thanks in regard! :)

[image]

Comment: Answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12220/3127 as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is now very easy to do efficiently. Add a spot lamp where you want it, and then add a cube and edit to just barely contain the spot lamp:

[image: SpotLamp1]

Make the material of the cube as shown. Note that the *Transparent* shader is not necessary, and you can leave the *Surface* input blank. However you can have a surface material *and* a volume material at the same time.

[image: Nodes]

Then add a plane as the ground and render:

[image: Render]

Since the volume is so small to render, it renders very quickly, this test render took about 3.5 seconds.

If you want to move your spot lamp, just parent the mesh to it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *> Object*.

Comment: no need of transparent BSDF.

Comment: Not necessary for functionality, but I still use it. It makes it clearer what is happening.

Comment: No need AND no side effect? (slower render or anything bad) I agree that getting things clearer can be useful.

Comment: On that I am not certain, I have noticed no major differences. That is a good question for a dev.

Comment: BTW, volume shaders tends to be better with more render samples, less noisy. The screenshot is very noisy because of a very low (and fast, good for testing) render/preview samples. For this you won't need many volume bounces anyway (0 should do).

Comment: I thought that was obvious enough for people :/

Comment: Maybe not for true novices (not in diguise :) )

Comment: It did worked! thanks a lot! 
Now...i want to know something...if i want to add an image texture to it, like a rainbow for example, where on the nodes should i have to add it?

Comment: For the volume color? You could try light falloff node and color ramp node.