# How to setup correctly the spot lamp

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light, lighting, shadows

Can someone give to me any suggestion to set up correctly the spot lamp ? I would like that the light is like the one that you see on the last attached picture. I watched a tutorial,I tried different kind of parameters,but I'm not fully satisfied....very thanks.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: increase the light size so that the shadows are softer. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347

Comment: How can I make the light wider ? as you can see,the light should have also a larger radius...

Comment: maybe something like this ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24493/is-it-possible-to-make-visible-spotlight-lightrays

Comment: To control the softness use lamp size. To have a wider radius change the spot shape size. To have volumetrics add volume scatter on the world or create a domain. Read:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154

Comment: ohhh nice. you are the n. 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the softness of the source move the **Lamp Size** value.

The larger the light source the softer the shadows (read: [How to minimize/soften the shadows?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347)).

[image]
(Click on the image to enlarge)

To change the radius of the light change the **Spot Shape Size** (in degrees).

[image]
(Click on the image to enlarge)

To have volumetrics add volume scatter on the world or create a domain.

[image]

read: [Atmospheric lighting in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/atmospheric-lighting-in-cycles/45154#45154)

Comment: I used a domain and this is the result that I've got : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gQCBxJvN-kMvQF2tUrwVMcF2SRLqspRl