# Looking for the logic behind some simple flat UI drop shadows

Tags: shadows

I'm currently trying to create continuity from a blender render to an element on an html page, and attempting to match the box-shadow property of an html element to the way drop shadow looks from a render.

Pretty much the only shading tool I have to work with while trying to imitate a render is this gradient argument called `box-shadow`.

One very popular example of box-shadow currently out there is material design (https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq), the shadows from which tend to look more life like.

In all of the shadows definitions are two sets of shadows:

`.card-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}`

These types of shadows definitely look closer than just a single gradient, but are still a bit off, so I'm trying to figure out what they're missing by reverse engineering the shadow from a render and imitating it with these simple gradients.

**Here's the part where a good understanding of Blenders (cycles) rendering logic comes in**

The parts of the shadow I think of as being most important to a shadow looking real are first the primary shadow (where the object blocks the light), followed by a sort of halo shadow (where the object blocks reflected light), and the halo shadow is also a bunch of light which softens the primary shadow.  I imagine that is why material design uses two shadows.

Is there any other simplifiable components to a shadow that come to mind?  I can also add white drop shadows/gradients to sort of imitate lighting.

Also, I apologize for this not being a strictly in the world of blender question, but this question is even more out of place in the html/design world.

Comment: "Shadow Catcher"

Comment: I think you may be referring to [Umbra and Penumbra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra) if it helps. Maybe posting some reference images of what you are trying to match and what you have so far will help. The way I see it you have three basic parameters you can play with, which are light positioning, light intensity, and light size which will affect shadow softness

Comment: Umbra and Penubra are just about exactly what I'm looking for, and I'm really excited about this wiki link.  Whatever it is I'm looking for, I imagine this is quite the lead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Antumbra was the exact missing piece I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe related?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/meaning-of-sun-lamp-size/44725#44725 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77336/how-to-minimize-soften-the-shadows/77347#77347 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95151/how-to-setup-correctly-the-spot-lamp/95159#95159