# How to create a visible spotlight without fog?

Tags: light

I know if we add a volumetric shader, the spot light act like this.[image]

But I don't want to be a foggy atmosphere, just the light should look like the volumetric like the below image.
[image]

I am looking for the exact result in the YouTube video - https://youtu.be/6wQynvx9y6g?t=47

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/how-can-a-light-cone-volumetric-be-setup-with-cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a spot light with Max Bounces 1 and shape a cone with the spot light.

[image: Spot light with 1 Bounce Max]

Cone material would be just simple volume scatter.

[image: Volume Scatter]

Now there's lot less light escaping to the environment. In the image below there are two light sources. Another one is just sharper and bit more powerful.

[image: End result]